# Quais as vantagens de usar arrays associativos?

Tags: php, array

Me deparei com a definição de *arrays associativos* que são vetores com índices formados por *strings*, exemplo:

```
$site['nome'] = "Stack Overflow";
```

Qual são as vantagens de usar esse tipo de vetores? Já que você não pode usar eles em uma estrutura de repetição, isso pode ser um demérito de se usar esse tipo de *array*. Esse método seria a forma de fazer um `struct` ou *dicionário* em PHP?

Comment: Também conhecido como **hash**.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

De acordo com o [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), os *arrays* associativos do PHP são "mapas ordenados". Há uma infinidade de situações nas quais eles podem ser úteis.

### Loops

A premissa não é correta, você pode usar numa estrutura de repetição sem problemas:

```
$teste = array( 'banana' => 'fruta', 'alface' => 'verdura' );
foreach( $teste as $key => $value ) {
   echo "$key é $value<br>\n";
}
```

### DBs

Há inúmeras situações onde usar *arrays associativos* facilita a vida. Uma delas, por exemplo, é no retorno de uma linha de um DB.

É muito mais fácil você entender um código com `$campos['nome']`, `$campos['idade']`... do que `$campos[1]`, `$campos[2]` ...

Além disso, se você usa índices numéricos neste caso, cria uma confusão imensa no código cada vez que acrescenta ou retira um campo da sua *query* original.

Em PHP especialmente, há muitas funções para se trabalhar com *arrays associativos*, tanto trabalhando com chave e valor, quanto cada uma das partes separadamente.

### JSON

Outro uso em que *arrays associativos* são fundamentais, é quando você precisa trabalhar com JSON.

Naturalmente, isto aqui:

```
"phoneNumbers": [
{
  "type": "home",
  "number": "212 555-1234"
},
{
  "type": "office",
  "number": "646 555-4567"
}
```

Pode ser representado assim:

```
array( "phoneNumbers" =>
   array( 
      array( "type" => "home", "number" => "212 555-1234" ),
      array( "type" => "office", "number" => "646 555-4567" )
   )
)
```

e vice-versa. o PHP já tem funções nativas que convertem um formato para outro.

### Formulários de web

Dentro da função primordial para que foi concebido, o PHP naturalmente usa os *arrays* associativos para receber os dados de formulários HTML, e de *query string*, usualmente através das variáveis `$_POST` e `$_GET`, entre outras.

Isto aqui:

```
<input type="text" name="batatinha">
```

ao ser recebido pelo PHP, já se transforma nisso:

```
$_POST['batatinha']
```

ou nisto, dependendo do método:

```
$_GET['batatinha']
```

Mais praticidade é até mais difícil de se imaginar. Isto se aplica a inúmeras outras situações, como envio de arquivos, por exemplo.

Imagine se tivéssemos que contar quantos campos o form tem, para acessar sequencialmente esta informação.

Comment: Pergunta de n00b em PHP: E quando você precisa de um array indexado por números, _#comofas_? Arrays associativos novamente ou a linguagem oferece alguma outra forma?

Comment: Já achei aqui. Usa-se um array associativo em que as chaves devem ser valores inteiros, sequenciais e iniciados por zero. Ou então constrói-se o array passando somente os valores e omitindo as chaves, que ficarão implícitas e obedecendo esse comportamento de serem inteiras, sequenciais e iniciadas por zero.

Comment: @Piovezan o associativo com numérico cai bem quando precisa pular algum número na sequência também, ou quando você precisar reordenar, mas mantendo a indexação original.

Answer (score 10):

Na verdade eles podem ter vários tipos de dados com chaves, não só *strings*.

Sua característica principal é que os dados são armazenados de forma esparsa, ou seja, não segue uma sequência contínua, como *arrays* comuns. Obviamente isso tem lá suas desvantagens.

Ele realmente é um dicionário, também chamado de tabela *hash* ou mapa de valores. Em PHP é usado para simular `struct`, já que o PHP não tem nada semelhante. Alguns dirão que uma classe pode simular uma `struct`. É verdade, mas o que muitos não sabem é que a classe em PHP é uma forma de *array* associativo, ela não é uma estrutura simples e continua como é em C ou outras linguagens tipicamente estáticas.

Ele pode ser usado em uma estrutura de repetição sim, ele consegue acessar todos os valores um a um, apenas sua organização interna é diferente.

No PHP ele é usado amplamente para receber dados que chegam externamente pelo servidor web ou por uma consulta ao banco de dados.

Comment: Uma coisa que eu percebi é que se você declara um array associativo com alguns elementos em uma certa ordem, e percorre esse array em um `for`, ele respeita a ordem de criação. Então talvez não sejam simples tabelas hash, estando mais para os tais mapas ordenados, correto? Porque em uma tabela hash a ordem de inserção não é preservada na hora de percorrer as chaves, se não estou enganado.

Comment: @Piovezan sim, não é bem *hash*, eu falei de forma simplificada, provavelmente é um árvore binária. Essas linguagens dinâmicas fazem objetos tudo da mesma forma, é um dicionário ordenado que se confunde com *hash*, mas por ter ordem, não é. tem resposta minha que eu falo com mais detalhes sobre isso, acabei não colocando aqui. Vou ver se melhoro sobre isso.